# Nintendo World and the "7 Stars" Concept

Tags: mario-series, legend-of-zelda-series

I always was super fan of Nintendo games and games for Nintendo, although I haven't played them all.

And I always had a curiosity about the **7 Stars** concept present in several games, like Super Mario RPG, Star Ocean and even The Legend of Zelda: Wind Waker.

Does it have a special meaning or a backstory related?

Comment: I believe Paper Mario also had 7 stars.  Now you've got me interested.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, seems like a decent question to me.

Comment: @Waterseas Give it time.  Some users just hate all lore questions.

Comment: I've not found an official word, but it might just be they like the number.  For stars there are: 7 stars in the Big Dipper, 5 planets visible to naked eye +sun +moon, also Pleiades is referred to as Seven Sisters.  There is also the Seven Heavens theme that is in several religious groups.  Furthermore, 7 is a special number in a few ways.  7 continents, 7 days of the week, 7 wonders of the world, 7 colors in the rainbow, pirates sail the 7 seas, 7 dwarves in Snow White.  Ok, maybe not so much that last one, but Super Mario 3 had 7 kingdoms and 7 koopa kids.

Comment: Personally, I don't think this is so much as a lore question as a developer design question.  I have voted accordingly.

Comment: I feel it's simply too broad. If it was specific to one game and/or series where it was a plainly evident article of lore content, then it *could* be a good question as long as it asked about objective narrative significance in a context-defined way rather than intended purpose, but the narrative meaning across so broad a spectrum is myriad and complex, making it a poor question. Without any clear factors tying the narratives together, answers would likely be speculative and/or incomplete. It does border on a numerology question though.

Comment: @skovacs1 Mario RPG is by Nintendo and Square Enix (at that time just Square), Windwaker is also Nintendo and Star Ocean is also Square Enix.  Common Publishers/Developers is also acceptable to me, as Bungie is another company that loves the number 7.

Comment: Zelda + Mario is one thing. Mario RPG + Star Ocean is another. If they were two separate questions what with them being two separate developers, that logic might fly. Even then, it asks developer intent because the only common factor is the developer. For it to be a lore question, it would have to be about the narrative and justifying association by common developer means it's actually asking developer intent and/or conspiracy theory.

Comment: I didn't think a Lore question would cause such repercussion, and I'm sorry for that. But this was the most appropriate Stack Exchange site I could post it, availing myself of sites' slogan "passionate videogamers on all platforms" AND, accordingly to community guideline, I'm not wrong as Lore questions can be subclassified as game terminology and plot. Although @Batophobia's answer makes sense, I don't think these are the reasons behind it. Also, the chosen tags are even worse now. :p

Comment: @skovacs1 The common factor of the developer makes it closer to the answer than the intent.  The base question still asks for whether or not there is some explanation for the 7-star theme.  If the answer is "because the developers like 7" then that in no way affects the question.

Comment: Closer to the answer than the intent? Closer to what answer? The base question asks for an explanation, agreed. The issue was never with the fundamental question, but with the scope as it assumes commonality across unconnected works. If it were clearly a lore question, it would be contained to *one* lore, however expansive. This spread makes it a developer intent question. Lore questions are fine, but the way this is asked makes it not a lore question. Even if each lore is referenced separately in the question, that's still a bad question for lumping separate questions into one.